# JMeter/Java: http connection timeout has effect on transactions per second (tps) on MacOS, not on CentOS

Tags: http, jmeter, jvm

I made simple testplan in `JMeter`: one thread with empty `http request` to `localhost` where there is no web server active at time of running the test. I run test from command line.

I noted that `http connection timeout` set in `HTTP sampler` has significant effect on `tps` on `MacOS`: 100 tps with 10 milliseconds connection timeout, 500 tps with 1 milliseconds connection timeout (2500 tps with Apache web server working).

However on CentOS server w/out web server at localhost (100% error rate during test) tps is 2500 regardless of timeout value. Why is that? Can it be some `jvm` parameter?

```
MacOS:
java 13 2019-09-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13+33)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13+33, mixed mode, sharing)

CentOS:
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

ADDED:

Following hint on immediate error I've tried: curl http://localhost and got `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused` immediately on both server and MacOS. Why then JMeter waits for timeout on MacOS only? anything else to check/try?

Comment: It sounds you don't reach timeout, you get immediate error

Comment: @user7294900, thank you. looks like more OS/networking setup issue?

Comment: @user7294900, i added info on trying curl. Can you provide any additional advice now?

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case you're launching Apache on one [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) ([alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing)) and JMeter is trying to connect to another IP address.

Double check that you're using the same IP in both Apache web server and JMeter and you should get the same results.

1. Apache [bind configuration](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html):

   ```
   Listen 127.0.0.1:80
   ```
2. JMeter [HTTP Request Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) configuration:

   [image]

---

If you have to use the hostname make sure that it's being resolved into correct IP address, for example it might be the case Apache web server is listening on [IPv4 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) and Java is trying to use [IPv6 endpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6). If this is the case you can enforce Java to use IPv4 stack by adding the next line to *system.properties* file

```
java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

You can also set up hostname/IP address custom resolution rules in the [DNS Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps/)

More information: [Java Networking Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html)

---

Last but not the least, it is not recommended to have the system under test and the load generator running on the same machine as JMeter is very resource intensive and both applications may start struggling for the OS resources (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc.) so it will be much harder to get to the bottom of the performance bottleneck due to mutual interference of both applications.

Comment: Dmitri, thank you for the info, however host is just `localhost` and `Apache` is stopped (`sudo apachectl stop`).